# How to get element in user-agent shadow root with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I need get elements from Shadow DOM and change it. How i can do it?

```
<div>
     <input type="range" min="100 $" max="3000 $">
</div>
```

Comment: I try .getElementById

Comment: I think `element.shadowRoot` represents the youngest shadow root that is hosted on the element !

Comment: I need to get an element that is inside the Shadow DOM

Comment: Please provide us with what you have tried so far. A single line of code is not much to go on. Questions asking us to write code for you do not typically belong here.

Comment: Inside input I have element with id="track". And I need get this element. How I can find it. I try .getElementById(track)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#example');
//Create shadow root !
var root = container.createShadowRoot();
root.innerHTML = '<div>Root<div class="test">Element in shadow</div></div>';

//Access the element inside the shadow !
//"container.shadowRoot" represents the youngest shadow root that is hosted on the element !
console.log(container.shadowRoot.querySelector(".test").innerHTML);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#example');
//Create shadow root !
var root = container.createShadowRoot();
root.innerHTML = '<div>Root<div class="test">Element in shadow</div></div>';

//Access the element inside the shadow !
console.log(container.shadowRoot.querySelector(".test").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="example">Element</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! But element <input type="range" min="100 $" max="3000 $"> has ShadowDOM with <div id="track">, and I need get this element.

Comment: The shadow root created on DIV ? because it can be created on the Input !

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in recent Firefox: `"message": "TypeError: container.createShadowRoot is not a function"`

Comment: Downvoted as this described creating a shadow root with the Javascript API, it does not describe access the browser-implemented shadow root. The response indicating you cannot access the shadow root generated by the browser (e.g. #shadow-root in Chrome) is more correct.

However, thank you for explaining creating one as well.

Comment: This does not answer how to access user-agent element's shadow-root (already created by browser). It shows how to access custom element's shadow-root (created by developer).

Comment: `createShadowRoot` is non-standard and deprecated. Neither Firefox nor Safari support it. **Don't use it.** Instead use `element.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});`.

Answer (score 34):

You cannot access a Shadow DOM created by the browser to display a control, that is called a `#shadow-root (user-agent)` in the Dev Tools. `<input>` is one example.

You can only access *open* custom Shadow DOM (the ones that you create yourself), with the `{ mode: 'open' }` option.

```
element.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
```

**Update**

It's true for most UX standard HTML elements: `<input>`, `<video>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, `<audio>`, etc.

**3rd party edit 2022**

The following might help to illustrate the question. Give there is only 1 `<input type=range>` in the html document this code shows if its children can be accessed.

```
 // returns 1 as expected since only one input element is in the document
document.querySelectorAll("input").length; 

// get a reference to <input type=range>
var rangeInput = document.querySelector("input");     

// Is it a shadowRoot?
// if null then either 
//   - it is not a shadowRoot OR 
//   - its elements can not be accessed (mode == closed)
console.log(rangeInput.shadowRoot);  // returns null
```

The code above shows that the internals of an `<input type=range>` can not be accessed.

[image: input_type_range_shadowRoot_access]

Comment: I know that this post was 2 years ago, but do you have the source of this? Or are there any updates about this? I am trying to access the shadow dom that created by the iOS safari. Thanks.

Comment: Source of what? user-agent Shadow DOM are browser vendors native implementation so they are not documented and will never be accessible. Only open Shadow DOM are, as per the specs.

Answer (score 19):

To answer a generalized version of the OP's question:

### Query shadow elements FROM ANYWHERE on the page?

It feels like the shadow root API is still lacking. It seems to make `querySelectorAll` useless, in that `querySelectorAll` will not actually get **all** matching elements anymore, since it **ignores all descendants in `shadowRoots`**. Maybe there is an API that fixes that, but since I have not found any, I wrote my own:

This function recursively iterates all `shadowRoots` and gets you **all** matching elements on the page, not just those of a single `shadowRoot`.

```js
/**
 * Finds all elements in the entire page matching `selector`, even if they are in shadowRoots.
 * Just like `querySelectorAll`, but automatically expand on all child `shadowRoot` elements.
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692555/2228771
 */
function querySelectorAllShadows(selector, el = document.body) {
  // recurse on childShadows
  const childShadows = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll('*')).
    map(el => el.shadowRoot).filter(Boolean);

  // console.log('[querySelectorAllShadows]', selector, el, `(${childShadows.length} shadowRoots)`);

  const childResults = childShadows.map(child => querySelectorAllShadows(selector, child));
  
  // fuse all results into singular, flat array
  const result = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
  return result.concat(childResults).flat();
}
```

```js
// examples:
querySelectorAllShadows('td'); // all `td`s in body
querySelectorAllShadows('.btn') // all `.btn`s in body
querySelectorAllShadows('a', document.querySelector('#right-nav')); // all `a`s in right menu
```

Comment: That's not really an omission, its by design, and its the main mechanism by which shadowDOM 'encapsulates' styles and namespace. querySelect/+all is a method of the capital D Document interface of which lowercase d document is the most famous member, but Shadowroots are also documents (or document fragments, really). Documents within documents within documents... its documents all the way down man

Comment: Shadow roots have many purposes. Being able to search/interact with elements of the entire `Page`, rather than an individual `Document`, is still necessary at times.

Comment: For sure, and in those instances I do end up using a little more verbose syntax as a ‘workaround’ (I.e, one must query the shadow root host element first before querying it’s shadow descendants). But at least in my experience the “encapsulation by default” is convenient more often than it’s not, and it’s why I use shadowroots often.

Answer (score 0):

If your control is inside Shadow-root (user-agent). You can perform enter text, get value and click by using the Parent of Shadow-root (user-agent).

Example:

(Selenium/C# code) - same should work for others as well

```
//You can use any identifier like id, XPath, tagname, etc
Var element = Driver.FindElement(By.Tagname("input"));
//Text will return null, so use below code
var text = element.GetAttribute("value");
or
element.Click();
or
element.Sendkeys("Entered text");
```