# How to traverse a Shadow DOM in Google Calendar or any third party's web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-calendar-api, shadow-dom

I am trying to traverse to a Shadow DOM's  node in a web page's  node.

This

```
$("input[title='From time']").shadowNode.children('div')
```

won't work.

Below, is an image of some of the Source

[image]

I am trying to extract 9:30pm. Or are user-agent shadow DOMs not accessible?

If so .. What could be my next approach to get this element ?

Comment: Don't add images of code. Just paste here the codes. That will be very easy for us to answer in a correct way.

Comment: It's not a third party Shadow DOM but a user-agent Shadow DOM... so you cannot access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38701803/4600982

Comment: use the Google Calendar API

Comment: @Supersharp Using the API is a good idea but I want to access time whenever a user makes changes in time, which is before the User saves the event, so Google Calendar API does not serve the purpose.