# How to get the value of an invalid HTML date input?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, html-input

I am building a calendar picker to accompany (and replace the default calendar date picker provided by some browsers) an `input` of `type="date"`.

It is documented that for "simplicity" that Chrome's (and possibly other browsers) date input allows invalid dates to be inputted, but they will fail to validate (ie. 31/06/2017 can be inputted, but produces a "value" of "").

When an invalid date is entered into the input, how can I get the value of that invalid date?

```js
var date_input = document.getElementById('date_input');
var output_div = document.getElementById('output_div');

output_div.innerHTML = date_input.value;

date_input.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    output_div.innerHTML = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<p>To quickly input an invalid date, select the day field and press the down arrow (on Chrome OSX this displays an empty div below the input instead of the invalid date). This will select 31/06/2017</p>
<input type="date" value="2017-06-01" id="date_input" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="output_div" />
```

Comment: If you are using input type date, then how will the date value be invalid ?

Comment: @sajalsuraj, as mentioned, you _can_ enter (either manually, or by pressing on the arrow keys) a date such as `31/06/2017` (there are only 30 days in june). The input _allows_ this value to be entered and displayed, but does not return it as its "value" when queried using Javascript)

Answer (score 5):

## Not like this

```js
var date_input = document.getElementById( 'date_input' );
var output_div = document.getElementById( 'output_div' );

output_div.textContent = date_input.valueAsDate; // :-)

date_input.addEventListener( 'input', function( evt ){
    var val = date_input.value,
        sel = document.getSelection();
    if ( date_input.validity.badInput ) {
        // date_input.focus(); // with or without this,
        // date_input.select(); // this doesn't work but,
        // due to the added <span> wrapper:
        sel.selectAllChildren( date_input.parentElement );
        // this does. So:
        val = sel.toString() || function() {
            var copied = document.execCommand( 'copy' );
            sel.empty(); // clear the selection
            return "Invalid date" + ( copied ? " copied to clipboard." : "" );
        }();
    }
    output_div.textContent = val;
});
```

```css
#output_div {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>To quickly input an invalid date, select the day field and press the down arrow (on Chrome OSX this displays an empty div below the input instead of the invalid date). This will select 31/06/2017</p>
<span><input type="date" value="2017-06-01" id="date_input"></span>
<div id="output_div"></div>
```

Apparently since the `value` shown is actually the *output* of the [shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom) *child* of the `<input>`, and [we can't access the `user-agent`'s shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701803/how-to-get-element-in-shadow-root-with-javascript#38736220), the visible value is effectively unknown to JS.

For [accessibility reasons](https://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/#article-header-id-16), the visible value has to be accessible to screen readers and the like, and can also be *manually* copied to the clipboard.

Having tried multiple ways of programmatically selecting and copying the text, I have run out of ideas and patience, and could only manage to copy it to the clipboard.

- If someone else can figure out how to read the `aria-value*` attributes of the `#shadow-root (user-agent)` with JS, then you have a way forward.
- If someone else can figure out how to assign the `selection` string to a `var`, you have another way forward.

### However

Since the invalid input is limited to being predictably out of range, you could monitor what the last valid `value` was before it was changed to something invalid, then calculate what it must surely now be.

- If using the datepicker, all the inputs will be valid.
- If typing, monitor the keystrokes.
- If using the arrow buttons, and the date was `30/06/2017` before a change that rendered it invalid, and `29/06/2017`, `30/05/2017`, `30/07/2017`, `30/06/2016` and `30/06/2018` are all valid, the invalid date must be `31/06/2017`.

I have **not** experimented (yet) with making that work, but am confident it can. I would be posting that solution with this answer, but half my day has been swallowed by this question already and I'm hungry. If a sincere interest is expressed, I will happily try and provide the codez.

### Still no good

This will display invalid dates if they're created using the arrow buttons, and only if the last date was valid. I could probably find a way around that, but officially give up! Life's too short.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> ... the displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's operating system.

This would make tracking keystrokes unreasonably non-trivial.

However, I just discovered [`<input type="datetime-local">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) which might solve that issue, and could possibly solve others.

### So this does something useful:

But trying to force this to work is beginning to feel like trying to insert a watermelon where one would not usually be expected to fit.

It's a ham-fisted kludge with little to no charm, that is likely to break if anyone looks at it too hard. Best disclaimer ever right ;)

```js
var date = "",
    input = document.querySelector( "input" ),
    output = document.querySelector( "output" ),
    bits = function( d ) {
        return [ d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate() ];
    },
    adjustedDate = function( o ) {
        var d = new Date( date ),
            b = bits( d ),
            year = b[ 0 ],
            month = b[ 1 ],
            day = b[ 2 ];
        switch ( o.i ) {
            case "d": return [ year, month, ( day + o.v ) || 31 ];
            case "m": return [ year, month + o.v, day ];
            case "y": return [ year + o.v, month, day ];
        }
    },
    calcDate = function() {
        var ad, vd, rd;
        [ { i: "d", v: 1 },
          { i: "d", v: -1 },
          { i: "m", v: 1 },
          { i: "m", v: -1 },
          { i: "y", v: 1 },
          { i: "y", v: -1 }
        ].forEach( ( v ) => {
            ad = adjustedDate( v ).join( "-" );
            vd = bits( new Date( ad ) ).join( "-" );
            if ( ad !== vd ) {
                rd = ad;
            }
        } );
        return rd.split( "-" ).map( ( v ) => {
            v = v.toString();
            return v.length === 1 ? "0" + v : v;
        } ).join( "-" ); // tired so mental
    },
    showDate = function() {
        output.textContent = date = ( input.value || calcDate() );
    };
showDate();
input.addEventListener( "input", showDate, false );
```

```css
output {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>To quickly input an invalid date, select the day field and press the down arrow. This will select 31/06/2017 and output the desired invalid date string.</p>
<form><input type="date" value="2017-06-01"><output></output></form>
```

Comment: Copying the text is an interesting workaround. I like it as a potential solution far better than the "however" section. Reason being that a date like `29/02/2012` has two places that, if changed, render the value invalid (up arrow on day, or up/down arrow on year), and i can think that the number keystokes option would only make the possibilities of invalid options hugely difficult to manage (especially given `min` and `max` attribute options)

Comment: @haxxxton - The practical alternative (if nothing else comes along) is to build your own datepicker. I ran into problems trying to use the HTML5 colorpicker and rather than wasting time trying to force it to behave, I just built my own - which is both satisfying and far sexier than the HTML5 version. I may work on the "however" solution anyway - for fun. If I have any success, I'll post it.

Comment: Yeah, if it wasnt for the handy convenience of what it does out of the box for the most part and time constraints on what im working on i would definitely go down that path. The calendar picker that ive built attached to it works great, its really only the interaction with the date picker itself that causing the issues at all.. keep us posted if you do find a solution to 'however' as id be happy to try and break it.. erm test it i mean ;)

Comment: Looks interesting, you're right it is relatively easy to break :P ie `29/02/2012` then up arrow on the year is resulting in a negative year.. and like you mentioned this only works for the first errorred date.. really appreciate the effort though! if only there was a way to detect the sections of the date that the keypress is occurring on :\

Comment: Easy to break, but **possible** to fix. An alternative to the lack of access to the user-agent shadow-root, is to copy it and all its dependancies (manually) and [create a custom shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) from the copy and add it to a `<input type="text">`. That should give you access to the value(s) and in theory will function identically.