# How to tell if user agent Shadow Dom is open or closed?

Tags: python, html, selenium, shadow-dom

I have the following typical shadow dom html code:

```
<input is="text-input" class="input-element style-scope paper-input" 
autocomplete="off" placeholder="" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" 
aria-describedby="" aria-labelledby="paper-input-label-22" id="input-22" 
tabindex="0">
   #shadow-root (user-agent)
   <div id="inner-editor">test</div>
</input>
```

I am using Selenium to try to get the text inside the  of the shadow root, but it always returns null, I know the differences between open vs closed shadow DOM, and the open version of Shadow dom always displays as #shadow-root (open) in my Devtool, so I am wondering how can I tell if this user-agent shadow dom is open or closed?

Edit: I am using JS and my code look like this:

```
driver.executeScript("return 
    arguments[0].shadowRoot",driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("#input-
    22"))).then(function(text) { text.getText()});
```

text come back as null.

Comment: Do you have a public example of this that you can link? I'd like to try some things out.

Comment: I don't, this is part of a project that I am working on to write tests with. I would access shadow-root that is marked as (open) with no problem, but with the (user-agent) ones they always come back as null, which makes me think they are closed shadow DOMs.

Comment: Understood... do you know of any public/example pages that might be formatted like this that we can see?

Comment: Maybe this page is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701803/how-to-get-element-in-shadow-root-with-javascript

Comment: Yes it's relevant. User-agent shadow dom are somewhat closed... sorry!

Comment: What language are you using? Java? You haven't posted any code.

Comment: What happens if you do something like `driver.findElement(By.id("input-22")).getAttribute("innerHTML")`? Does it dump the shadow-root elements, etc. then?

Comment: I am using JS. When I tried to use that kind of code, it returns null, which is why I was suspecting it is a closed kind of shadow DOM vs open, which I also tested on and it works. So user-agent shadow DOMs are created by the browser itself and can not be accessed at this time.

Comment: The DOM within a `#shadow-root (user-agent)` is generated by the browser itself and is not accessible compared to a `#shadow-root ` which is via `shadowRoot`. Note that the text from the `<div>` is accessible via the `value` property from the `<input>`. Thus to get the text: `driver.findElement(By.css("#input-22")).getAttribute("value")`.

Comment: @JeffC When I did that it returned null

Comment: @FlorentB. it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @FlorentB. suggests,

```
driver.findElement(By.css("#input-22")).getAttribute("value"‌​)
```

will return the text value of the user agent shadow root.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell by seeing if the `innerHTML` of the root element is empty or not, see this example

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

driver.get("chrome://settings")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('settings-ui')

html_of_interest=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML',root1)
sel_soup=BeautifulSoup(html_of_interest, 'html.parser')
sel_soup# empty root not expande

shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

html_of_interest=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML',shadow_root1)
sel_soup=BeautifulSoup(html_of_interest, 'html.parser')
sel_soup
```

[image]