# How to apply CSS to element in Shadow DOM?

Tags: css, shadow-dom

How can I apply CSS to a element in Shadow DOM?

```
<div pseudo="-internal-media-controls-overflow-menu-list" style="bottom: 647px !important; right: 396px !important;">
```

I want to change bottom and right style of this element in Shadow DOM of `<video>` tag.

P.S Basically I want to overwrite the styling of an element in Shadow DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element in shadow root with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701803/how-to-get-element-in-shadow-root-with-javascript)

Comment: Can you give more of an example of what you have tried and what you are trying to do? Your example really doesn't show much.