# I want to change the HTML text displayed by: #shadow root (user-agent)

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for your help. After looking everywhere on the web I didn't find help to change (not to create) an html text in a #shadow-root: delete the comma (for french format). (Big numbers: Thousand separator for US numbers format)

Here is the html source code:

```
<div id="numbers">
    <input type="text"  id="sleeping"></input>
</div>
```

Here is the code in the browser DevTools (F12) in Chrome!

```
<div id="numbers">
    <span class="e-widget e-pinch e-numeric e-valid">
        <span class="e-in-wrap e-box e-padding">
            <input type="text" data-role="none" tabindex="0" accesskey="" value="8000" class="e-input" style="display: block;">
                #shadow-root (user-agent)
                <div>8,000</div>
            </input>
            <input type="text" id="sleeping" class="e-numerictextbox e-js e-input" tabindex="" accesskey="" name="sleeping" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="10000" aria-valuenow="8000" aria-live="assertive" value="8000" style="display: none;">
                #shadow-root (user-agent) == $0
                <div>8000</div>
            </input>
            <span class="e-select">
                <span class="e-spin e-spin-up " role="button" "aria-label"="Increase Value" unselectable="on">
                    <span class="e-icon e-arrow e-arrow-sans-up" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                        ::before
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="e-spin e-spin-down" role="button" "aria-label"="Decrease Value" unselectable="on">
                    <span class="e-icon e-arrow e-arrow-sans-down" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                        ::before
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

So I want to delete the comma: 8,000 to 8000 with a Javascript code. But I do not know how to access the div `<div>8,000</div>` under #shadow-root
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `parseInt(document.querySelector("#shadow-root").innerText.replace(/[, ]/g, ""))` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the `shadowRoot` of the element, then find its child node and update the content.

```
    const input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    const shadow = input.shadowRoot;
    const element = shadow.firstChild; // the div you want to access
    element.innerHtml = element .innerHtml.replace(/\,/g,'');
```

Comment: Thank you Stundji! But it gives an error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Comment: And it doesn't find < div>8,000< /div> //The number with comma (,)

Comment: Then you will need to provide a working example so I can work on your code. You can use https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here a picture: that's the Chrome DevTools (F12) displaying;
I want to get "value: 4,000" in a var.

[HTMLCollection: get value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVqlF.png)

Comment: If I could get var MyVar = 4,000; I could transform it to 4000 (without comma) in my web site page.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably user-agent shadow-root. I am looking for a way to manipulate it right now, I have found already some information that you can't do it, since it's not in open mode and you cannot put it in that mode...

[How to get element in user-agent shadow root with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701803/how-to-get-element-in-user-agent-shadow-root-with-javascript)