# Cypress interacting with shadow dom button

Tags: cypress, shadow-dom

**HTML screen shot**

[image: html screen shot]

I am unable to interact with a shadow dom button using cypress
I have tried with and without adding `"includeShadowDom": true` to the cypress.json.

I have tried various permutations of the code below and it continually fails to locate the element.

Just using `.shadow()` with the parent displays an error stating a shadow dom can't be found.

```js
cy.get('#r-searchField').shadow().find('#text-field-container').find('#search-clear').click()
```

Comment: How about you use `cy.get('#r-searchField').shadow().find('#search-clear').click({force: true})` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. "Timed out retrying after 15000ms: Expected the subject to host a shadow root, but never found it."

Answer (score 5):

You have `#shadow-root (user-agent)`, which means the browser is creating the shadow DOM.

According to this answer [How to get element in user-agent shadow root with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38736220/16791505) you cannot get to this type of shadow DOM with javascript.

> You cannot access a Shadow DOM created by the browser to display a control, that is called a **#shadow-root (user-agent)** in the Dev Tools. `<input>` is one example.
>
> You can only access open custom Shadow DOM (the ones that you create yourself), with the `{ mode: 'open' }` option.

Try clicking the input instead

```js
cy.get('input#r-searchField').click()
```