# 3cx change bubble button style in Wordpress functions.php - move up an async button and styling it after waiting fetch for async dom created

Tags: button, jquery-selectors, chat, shadow-dom, 3cx

I have been struggling with the moving up of the chat bubble overriding my theme bottom login/out web app bar for 2 days:

Tryed to:

1. modify in Wordpress the child style.css and the functions.php

The style of the theme was not applying
in style.css modified the <button id="wplc-chat-button"

```
`/* 
 Theme Name:   Alukas child
 Theme URI:    
 Description:  Tema child di Alukas
 Author:       admin
 Author URI:   https://monbi.it
 Template:     alukas
 Version:      1.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

 /* == Add your own styles below this line ==
--------------------------------------------*/
#wplc-chat-button {bottom: 100px!important}
`
```

2. using jquery to add css to the chat bubble
   after manually applying the bottom:70px!important to Chrome
3. using jquery to add css to the chat bubble parent div
4. using jquery to add css to the chat bubble grandparent div

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: @danny-365csi-engelman
copy paste the code below in functions.php of your wordpress with 3cx chat plugin installed (https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-live-chat-support)

Answer (score 1):

```
    function add_custom_js() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function querySelectorAllShadows(selector, el = document.body) {
          // recurse on childShadows
          
             /**
             * Finds all elements in the entire page matching `selector`, even if they are in shadowRoots.
             * Just like `querySelectorAll`, but automatically expand on all child `shadowRoot` elements.
             * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692555/2228771
             */
          const childShadows = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll('*')).
            map(el => el.shadowRoot).filter(Boolean);

          // console.log('[querySelectorAllShadows]', selector, el, `(${childShadows.length} shadowRoots)`);

          const childResults = childShadows.map(child => querySelectorAllShadows(selector, child));
          
          // fuse all results into singular, flat array
          const result = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
          return result.concat(childResults).flat();
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
            // sposta la bubble chat
                
            // Sposta il div #callus-container
                var allMatches = querySelectorAllShadows('#wp-live-chat-by-3CX');
                if(allMatches && allMatches.length > 0){
                    var callusContainer = jQuery(allMatches[0]); // Prendi il primo match
                    if(window.innerWidth <= 430) {
                        callusContainer.css({'position':'fixed','bottom':'105px','right':'5px'});
                    }
                }
                
            }, 3000);  // 3 secondi di ritardo
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_js', 100);
```

Comment: the main struggle have been to deal with async creation of the button
solved with a js delay of 3 sec.
and that the jQuery querySelectorAll function that it is not working inside the shadow-dom created

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?